# Integration of $p\left({1\over p^2+1}+{{1-p^2}\over (1+p^2)^2}\right)$ for $dp$

Tags: integration

Find :

$$\int p\left({1\over {p^2+1}}+{{1-p^2}\over {(1+p^2)^2}}\right) dp$$

My try:

$${1\over p^2+1}+{1-p^2\over (1+p^2)^2}={2\over (1+p^2)^2}$$

Then

$$\int p\left({1\over p^2+1}+{1-p^2\over (1+p^2)^2}\right) dp=\int {{2p\over{(1+p^2)}^2}}dp$$

But i don't know how can I complete :( ?

Comment: @Max Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: You should be able to compute the integral in the last line.

Comment: Please verify the edits.

Comment: Hint : $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^a}dx=\int \frac{1}{u^a}du=...$

Comment: @Evariste Thank you so much I understand that , so the answer: ${-1\over {1+p^2}}+c$ true ?

Comment: @Dima Well done :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer:

$\int {2p\over {(1+p^2)}^2} dp$

Let $u=1+p^2$

So $du=2p dp$

Then

$\int {2p\over {(1+p^2)}^2} dp=\int {du\over u^2}$

$={-1\over u}+c$

And in the first step we letting $u=1+p^2$

So the answer is:

$={-1\over {1+p^2}}+c$

Thanks @Evariste and @Mathmajor for help :)

https://math.stackexchange.com/users/239682/evariste

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1979015/324616

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $1 + p^2=u$ then $2p \, dp = du$ and we get

$$\int {{2p \, dp\over{(1+p^2)}^2}} =\int \frac{du}{u^2}$$